# using all callin different targets in makefile

Tags: make

I wrote a `makefile` as given below:

```
.PHONY: clean_lib all

a: lib
        make $@.exe

c: lib
        make $@.exe

clean_lib:
        rm -f lib

all: a clean_lib c
```

When I call `make all` I would like the "a" target to build a `lib` and `a.exe` and after that "clean" that `lib` and then call "c". which would build again `lib` for "c" and build `c.exe`.

Here the `a.exe` and `c.exe` only builds if `lib` builds. The problem is that after "clean" the `lib` that I want to rebuild for "c" is not building, so 
`c.exe` cannot build.

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: Why have to clean `lib` in the middle? It should work without cleaning it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you need to clean `lib` in the middle. I think it should work without cleaning.

```
.PHONY: all

lib: somesource
        make lib

a: lib
        make $@.exe

c: lib
        make $@.exe

all: a c
```

Both `a` and `c` depend on `lib`. Whenever you want to build `a`, `c` or both `lib` will be built. Once it is built it shouldn't need to be built again unless its source code (`somecode`) is changed.

That's how *makefiles* work, they keep track of dependencies and only need to rebuild something if the thing they depend on has been modified more recently than the target.

Comment: but if the different lib is builds for a and c?\

Comment: Then why not keep 2 copies of "lib" with 2 different names?

Comment: i want to change a variable in each case builds the lib

Comment: Indeed, have 2 copies of "lib", called "lib1" and "lib2", each one with its own set of variables.